# How do I remove the facebookWebView after logging in? Flash Builder 4.6 ios development

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

After the facebook button is pushed, the user logs in and then that webview immediately goes to the facebook mobile site.  What I need is for that webview to disappear so I can continue interacting with my app, and not the facebook mobile site.

I apologize if I'm not being clear, its 5am and I'm, going a little crazy here lol.  Take a look at the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    backgroundColor="#2F28C1" title="Setup"
    creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import views.setup_first.facebook;
        import views.setup_first.flickr;
        import views.setup_first.google;
        import views.setup_first.tumblr;
        import views.setup_first.twitter;

        public var permissions:Array = ["user_birthday", "read_stream", "publish_stream"];

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            FacebookMobile.init("262320357178421", loginHandler);

        }

        protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void
        {


        }

        protected function login():void
        {
            var facebookWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
            facebookWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle (0,0, stage.width, stage.height);
            FacebookMobile.login(loginHandler, this.stage, permissions, facebookWebView);
            trace("I'm logged in!");

        }

        protected function logout():void
        {
            FacebookMobile.logout(onLogout, "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=262320357178421&display=touch&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&type=user_agent&perms=publish_stream&fbconnect=1");

        }

        protected function onLogout(result:Object):void
        {
            trace("Perfect Log Out!")
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:navigationContent/>

<s:Button left="62" top="86" click="navigator.pushView(views.setup_first.google)"
          icon="@Embed('../Setup/Setup_0002_Layer-5.png')"/>

<s:Button right="64" top="86" click="login()" icon="@Embed('../Setup/Setup_0001_Layer-6.png')"/>

<s:Button click="navigator.pushView(views.setup_first.tumblr)" horizontalCenter="-4"
          icon="@Embed('../Setup/Setup_0000_Layer-7.png')" verticalCenter="-14"/>

<s:Button left="62" bottom="117" click="navigator.pushView(views.setup_first.flickr)"
          icon="@Embed('../Setup/Setup_0004_Setup.png')"/>

<s:Button right="63" bottom="117" click="navigator.pushView(views.setup_first.twitter)"
          icon="@Embed('../Setup/Setup_0005_Layer-1.png')"/>

<s:Button right="54" bottom="10" label="Skip" click="navigator.pushView(thirdPage)"/>
<s:Button id="logOut" x="323" y="210" height="28" label="LogOut" fontSize="15"
          click="logout()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Corey I don't know if you resolved your question but I did just a moment, so I will tell you about my experience.

With your code if the user logged in, and install the app in his applications of facebook, the loginHandler is dispatched with the FacebookSession in success, and facebookWebView is removed automatically. 
But If the user cancel the install or don't allow the requested permissions there is not any event dispatched and facebookWebView show a white page with the word "Success".
I have fixed this adding listeners to facebookWebView of location chage event. Then always facebookWebView change the url showed the method is dispatched, including when there is the error of user denied (dispatched when the user don't allow the app).
This is my code:

```
private var facebookWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 

protected function login():void{
    facebookWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChange);
    facebookWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, locationChange);
    facebookWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.width, stage.height);
    FacebookMobile.login(onLogin, this.stage, permissions, facebookWebView);
}

private function locationChange(e:LocationChangeEvent):void
{
    var url:String = e.location;
    if(url.search("error") != -1)
        removeFacebookView();   
}

protected function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
    if(success){
        //save user content FacebookSession(success).user
        removeFacebookView();
        setCurrentState("login");   
    }
}

private function removeFacebookView():void
{   
    facebookWebView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChange);
    facebookWebView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, locationChange);
    this.actionBarVisible = true;
    facebookWebView.stage = null;
}
```

As you can see to remove the facebookWebView I have a variable in the view, not a local variable of the function. (You can get it with e.target too). And you will remove it with facebookWebView.stage = null; Don't remove the eventlistener before. Only when loginhandle is dispatched with success, and when there is an error and you must to remove facebookWebView.